# Change gravity programmatically on ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview, gravity

I would like to have a ListView in which some items render on the left, and some on the right. I don't really know how to make this happen though. I was thinking of calling `setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)` on the `View` my adapter's `getView()` method returns, but that method apparently exists only for `ViewGroup`, which makes me think it would actually change the gravity of the object's contents. It would look something like this:

```
getView(int position, View toReturn, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Holder pattern, *yawn*

    if (needsToBeOnRight) {
        toReturn.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)

        // or whatever it is I'm actually supposed to do
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

The `View` represented by `toReturn` is expected to be a `RelativeLayout`, so I supppose in theory I could cast it to one and try the above, but as discussed above, I doubt that will work. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was almost there. In order to make it work, I had to wrap the view I want to right-or-left-orient in a FrameLayout. That would make `toReturn` in the above code a FrameLayout.

```
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) toReturn.getTag();

// Get the view's LayoutParams. In this case, since it is wrapped by a FrameLayout,
// that is the type of LayoutParams necessary.
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.viewThatMightNeedToBeOnRight.getLayoutParams();

// Set gravity to right or left as necessary within the LayoutParams.
if (params != null) {
    if (needsToBeOnRight) {
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    } else {
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    }

    // Assign the newly edited LayoutParams to the view.
    holder.viewThatMightNeedToBeOnRight.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams lay = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lay.gravity      = Gravity.END;

mListView.setLayoutParams(lay);
```